# Click an element on first Google search result using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

Hello I'm just new to puppeteer and having a problem here by a week now and
I just want to click on search result after searching the word 'Intel' on Google:

[image]

My source code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function search()  {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome',
    headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1600, height: 1040 })
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
            await page.type('input.gLFyf.gsfi', 'Intel');
            page.keyboard.press('Enter');
            await page.waitForSelector('a');
   
            await navigationPromise
            var selectorString = '.yuRUbf > a > .LC20lb';
            var selector = await page.$(selectorString);
            if (selector!=null) {
                var element = selector.asElement();
                await element.click();
            }

  await browser.close();
        }
        search();
```

I assume the problem is here

```
var selectorString = '.yuRUbf > a > .LC20lb';
```

Comment: You are using jQuery assuming that the page already has it loaded `page.$(selectorString);`. This won't work everytime and is best you use `document.querySelector(selectorString)` instead. This may or may not be the solution youre looking for. Adding more information about the specifc error you're having in your question would help you and others.

Comment: Those classes don't look reliable, use things that don't change like `input[name=q]`

Comment: The clicking function works on Bing the question is why it's not working on Google.

Answer (score -1):

This approach is on the right track but seems rather brittle. Prefer CSS selectors that are as generic as possible to help tolerate updates to the DOM structure.

In your code, `navigationPromise` is undefined; prefer [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) here to respond to the navigation triggered by the Enter key press.

`await page.waitForSelector('a');` seems too weak to achieve much since most pages already have anchors all over them, so the predicate will be trivially true. Use a more precise selector.

Your approach to clicking can be simply `page.click(selector)` as shown below:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  const searchQuery = "intel";

  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto("https://www.google.com/", {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector('input[aria-label="Search"]', {visible: true});
  await page.type('input[aria-label="Search"]', searchQuery);
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}),
    page.keyboard.press("Enter"),
  ]);
  await page.waitForSelector(".LC20lb", {visible: true});
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}),
    page.click(".LC20lb"),
  ]);
  console.log(await page.title()); // => Intel | Data Center Solutions, IoT, and PC Innovation
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser.close());
```

I'll add the standard note that disabling JS and blocking resources like images and stylesheets will substantially speed up the script. [Scraping Google search result links with Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515088/scraping-google-search-result-links-with-puppeteer/67523645#67523645) shows one approach to grab the data with a simple HTTP request and static HTML parser like cheerio.