# Scraping Google search result links with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Below is the code I'm trying to use for web scraping Google. When I pass in a specific request, it doesn't return the list of links. I don't understand what's causing it. Can someone help, please?

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const searchGoogle = async (searchQuery) => {
  /** by default puppeteer launch method have headless option true*/
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");
  await page.type('input[aria-label="Search"]', searchQuery);
  await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

  /** waitfor while loding the page, otherwise evaulate method will get failed. */
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  const list = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let data = [];
    /** this can be changed for other website.*/
    const list = document.querySelectorAll(".rc .r");
    for (const a of list) {
      data.push({
        title: a
          .querySelector(".LC20lb")
          .innerText.trim()
          .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "),
        link: a.querySelector("a").href,
      });
    }
    return data;
  });

  await browser.close();
};
module.exports = searchGoogle;
```

Answer (score 6):

`await page.waitFor(5000);` in this context causes a race condition. If the page doesn't load in 5 seconds, you can get a false negative. If the page loads quicker than 5 seconds, you've wasted time without reason. Only pick arbitrary delays as a last resort or if it's an intended part of the application logic.

A better approach is to use [`page.waitForSelector`](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) or [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/#pagewaitfornavigationoptions).

Secondly, I don't see results for the selector `.rc .r`. I'm not sure how stable Google's CSS selectors are, but `.LC20lb` seems safe on cursory glance for the time being.

Putting it together gives:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

let browser;
(async () => {
  const searchQuery = "stack overflow";

  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", request => {
    request.resourceType() === "document" ? 
      request.continue() : request.abort();
  });
  await page.goto("https://www.google.com/", {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector('input[aria-label="Search"]', {visible: true});
  await page.type('input[aria-label="Search"]', searchQuery);
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}),
    page.keyboard.press("Enter"),
  ]);
  await page.waitForSelector(".LC20lb", {visible: true});
  const searchResults = await page.$$eval(".LC20lb", els => 
    els.map(e => ({title: e.innerText, link: e.parentNode.href}))
  );
  console.log(searchResults);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Output (yours may be different depending on what Google shows by the time you run the script):

```js
[
  {
    title: 'Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build ...',
    link: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
  },
  {
    title: 'Stack Overflow - Wikipedia',
    link: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow'
  },
  {
    title: 'Stack Overflow Blog - Essays, opinions, and advice on the act ...',
    link: 'https://stackoverflow.blog/'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Stack Overflow Podcast - Stack Overflow Blog',
    link: 'https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/'
  },
  {
    title: 'Stack Overflow | LinkedIn',
    link: 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow'
  }
]
```

Another approach is to encode your search terms as a URL query parameter and navigate directly to `https://www.google.com/search?q=your+query+here`, saving a navigation and potential selector mishap.

As with many scraping tasks, since the goal is to grab simple hrefs from the document, you might try switching to `fetch`/`cheerio` and working with the static HTML. On my machine, the following script runs about 5x faster than Puppeteer with two navigations and about 3x faster than Puppeteer navigating directly to the search results.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const query = "stack overflow";
const url = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;

fetch(url, { // Node 18 or install node-fetch
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36",
  }
})
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const searchResults = [...$(".LC20lb")].map(e => ({
      title: $(e).text().trim(),
      link: e.parentNode.attribs.href,
    }));
    console.log(searchResults);
  });
```

See also [Click an element on first Google search result using Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470495/click-an-element-on-first-google-search-result-using-puppeteer/67523820#67523820).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a simple GET request to scrape the Google Search Results instead of using Puppeteer which is very CPU intensive.

Here is the code which can help you to scrape links from the Search Results Page:

```
const unirest = require("unirest");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const getOrganicData = () => {
  return unirest
    .get("https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript&gl=us&hl=en")
    .headers({
      "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36",
    })
    .then((response) => {
      let $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

      let titles = [];
      let links = [];
      let snippets = [];
      let displayedLinks = [];

      $(".yuRUbf > a > h3").each((i, el) => {
        titles[i] = $(el).text();
      });
      $(".yuRUbf > a").each((i, el) => {
        links[i] = $(el).attr("href");
      });
      $(".g .VwiC3b ").each((i, el) => {
        snippets[i] = $(el).text();
      });
      $(".g .yuRUbf .NJjxre .tjvcx").each((i, el) => {
        displayedLinks[i] = $(el).text();
      });

      const organicResults = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        organicResults[i] = {
          title: titles[i],
          links: links[i],
          snippet: snippets[i],
          displayedLink: displayedLinks[i],
        };
      }
      console.log(organicResults)
    });
};

getOrganicData();
```

If you want a complete explanation of this code, I have written a complete blog on it: [How to scrape Google Organic Search Results](https://serpdog.io/blog/scrape-google-organic-search-results)

Alternative:

You can use [Google Search API](https://docs.serpdog.io/google-search-api) by Serpdog. Serpdog also offers 100 free credits on the first signup.

Scraping can be time-consuming sometimes, but you can use this pre-cooked structured JSON data which makes your work easier, and also you don't have to maintain the Google CSS selectors from time to time which is a big headache.

How to use:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://api.serpdog.io/search?api_key=APIKEY&q=coffee&gl=us')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**Results:**

```
 "organic_results": [
{
  "title": "9 Health Benefits of Coffee, Based on Science - Healthline",
  "link": "https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/top-evidence-based-health-benefits-of-coffee",
  "displayed_link": "https://www.healthline.com › Wellness Topics › Nutrition",
  "snippet": "Coffee is a popular beverage that researchers have studied extensively for its many health benefits, including its ability to increase energy levels, promote ...",
  "rank": 1
},
{
  "title": "The Coffee Bean & Tea Leaf | CBTL",
  "link": "https://www.coffeebean.com/",
  "displayed_link": "https://www.coffeebean.com",
  "snippet": "Born and brewed in Southern California since 1963, The Coffee Bean & Tea Leaf® is passionate about connecting loyal customers with carefully handcrafted ...",
  "rank": 2
},
.......
```

*Disclaimer: I am the founder of [serpdog.io](https://serpdog.io).*